# why numpy.array is built-in?

Tags: python, numpy

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html,
the "built-in function" means a python-innate function such as `print` or `sum`.

However, `type(numpy.array)` results in `builtin_function_or_method` even though the numpy module is not python-innate.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `builtin_function_or_method` is not *really* testing if it is a *built in* (which is rather a bit ambiguous term). Rather, it tests if a function or method was written in C.

[From the official document](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/types.html#types.BuiltinMethodType):

> types.BuiltinFunctionType
>
> types.BuiltinMethodType
>
> The type of built-in functions like len() or sys.exit(), and methods of built-in classes. (Here, the term “built-in” means “written in C”.)

Comment: I haven't noticed that docs. Thank you :)